# Getting an error for the 2nd item in the list

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

Here is the problem:

[image: problem]

Here are the test that are ran with this code:

[image: test]

Here is the console:

[image: console]

I have written a code to sort two given lists and check if the combined list is in increasing order with no missing numbers in between. However, I am encountering an error with the code provided below:

The purpose of the code is to concatenate lst1 and lst2 into a new list called newlst. Then, the newlst is sorted in ascending order. The code iterates over the sorted list and checks if each element is followed by the next consecutive number. If there is a missing number between any two consecutive elements, the code should return False. If all the numbers are consecutive with no missing values, the code should return True.

```py
def consecutive_combo(lst1, lst2):
    newlst = lst1 + lst2
    newlst.sort()

    for x in range(len(newlst)):
        if newlst[x] + 1 != newlst[x + 1]:
            return False
        if newlst[x] + 1 == newlst[x + 1]:
            return True
```

Please help me debug.

Answer (score 1):

`return` statement is used to **end** the execution of the function call.. whenever `return` statement execute the function just return and end the function call..

The point is your code is just checking for first two values if it satisfy it prints true if it not it prints false.. to resolve this issue you can simple return true when for loop ends..
Below code..

```
def consecutive_combo(lst1, lst2):
    newlst = lst1 + lst2
    newlst.sort()

    for x in range(len(newlst)-1):
        if newlst[x] + 1 != newlst[x + 1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: `for x in range(len(newlst)):` should be `for x in range(len(newlist) - 1):` to avoid an index error.